# How to output jsonArray with html elements into JSP

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

First, please let me say that I recognize that having html saved in MySQL db is not ideal. But that's the way it's been setup and I just have to accept it and work with the existing set up.

So here's my issue.

I have a table "messages" that has "message" and "time" columns.

These are some sample values just for demonstration purposes:

MySQL:
"message" column:

```
You've received an appraisal from xyz re something in the amount of $1,2000.<br><a class='lnk' href='http://www.website.com/somepage.jsp?r=393'>View some page</a>
```

"time" column:

```
2015-12-16 15:51:33.0
```

I can retrieve the values in a java class and convert the resultset data into a jsonArray.

If I sysout the jsonArray, I can see the values from the table displayed more or less correctly.

```
System.out.println("jsonArray: " + jsonArray);
```

Output:

```
 jsonArray: [{"message":"You've received a message from xyz re something in the amount of $1,200.<br><a class='lnk' href='http://www.website.com/somepage.jsp?r=393'>View some page<\/a>","time":"2015-12-16 15:51:33.0"}]
```

I am struggling with two issues:

1) Returning html tags without being escaped in the output

Please notice the escaped  closing tag: </a> in the jsonArray above. Is there a way to retrieve it without the escape?

2) Returning jsonArray in jsp properly formatted and escaped.

I would like the JSP to return the jsonArray but I am not having much luck getting things to work correctly
 More specifically, I tried the following two to output the jsonArray on my jsp page:

```
out.print(jsonArray);

out.println(jsonArray.toString());
```

But in both cases, the escaped  closing tags seems to be causing issues.
The jsp output looks like this:

[image]

And this is the code generated in the jsp.

```
[{"message":"You've received an appraisal from xyz re something in the amount of $1,2000.<br><a class="lnk" href="http://www.website.com/somepage.jsp?r=393">View some page&lt;\/a&gt;","time":"2015-12-16 15:51:33.0"}]
```

Please notice the

```
   &lt;\/a&gt;
```

Could anyone please give me some tips how to properly format html tags in a jsonArray that contains data fetched from a database?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to escape your HTML?

Comment: @Jia Jian - I am looking to display the closing </a> without the escape <\/a>. I can't figure out what I need to do to have the "message" value in the jsonObject display </a> instead of <\/a>

Comment: Escape your starting `<a>` tag first, because it's messing up your JSON and making it invalid (use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) to check). Any specific reasons for not escaping it? It seems like your JSON response is returning `text/html` instead of `application/json`, is that intended?

Comment: @Jia Jian - thanks for the tip. setting the response.setContentType("application/json") & response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8") got me on the right track.
Please, post your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: posted as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning this into an answer.

Set your response type to `application/json` instead of `text/html` should do the trick.